# Left Justifications in Graphviz Nodes via HTML Formatting in Python

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz, leftalign

I'm using [the Python graphviz library](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and my nodes are formatted with HTML.

My python code generates this node:
`MyNode [label=<{Topic|<b>SubHeader</b>|field1: int<BR/>fields: dict<BR/>}>]`

[image]

I want to left align the text on the last (fields) section.

How do I add alignment instructions only for the last section?

Graphviz supports adding `\l` as a justification escape code, but it does not seem to work for HTML formatted nodes.
Similarly, I cannot figure out how to add `<p>` tags to the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 versions, 2 using html-like records:

```
graph {
  node [shape=Mrecord]
  MyNode [label=<{Topic|<b>SubHeader</b>|field1: int<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>fields: dict<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>}>]

  node [shape=plaintext]
  MyNodeA [label=<<table style="rounded">
       <tr><td border="0">Topic</td></tr>
       <hr/>
       <tr><td border="0"><b>SubHeader</b></td></tr>
       <hr/>
       <tr><td border="0" align="left">field1: int</td></tr>
       <tr><td border="0" align="left">fields: dict</td></tr>       
       </table>>]

  MyNodeB [label=<<table style="rounded">
       <tr><td border="0">Topic</td></tr>
       <hr/>
       <tr><td border="0"><b>SubHeader</b></td></tr>
       <hr/>
       <tr><td border="0" align="left" balign="left">field1: int<br/>fields: dict</td></tr>       
       </table>>]
}
```

giving:
[image]

Comment: Fabulous! I can’t mark both answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

- You failed to show that you had set node shape to Mrecord.  Hard to understand what you are doing without that information. Next time, please include an entire dot program.
- Wow, you are mixing record shapes and HTML text.  I'm surprised that is even legal.  It seems to be, so cool!
- \l, \r, \c  do not seem to be legal inside HTML text (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/lblString/)
- good news: `<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>` is legal.
  so:

```
graph {
  node [shape=Mrecord]
  MyNode [label=<{Topic|<b>SubHeader</b>|field1: int<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>fields: dict<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>}>]
}
```

Produces:
[image]

p.s. `<P>` is not legal Graphviz syntax.  See https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html  (Graphviz uses *HTML-like* syntax.  Emphasis on *-like*)
p.p.s.  Consider using actual HTML-like records.  They give more control.

Comment: • Sorry, will do. 
• Graphiv newbie, just fiddling around until it works :-)
• That was my impression too.
• Yes! Awseome - thanks!

Comment: Do you have a good example for "actual HTML-like records"? I found that the above works sporadically and unreliably.